# converting for-loops into while-loops

Tags: csh

Convert the for-loop in the following script to a while-loop.

```
echo "Enter a number"
read n
count=0
for((i=1; i <= n; i++))
do
    echo "Enter a number"
    read a
    if((a > 0))
       then
       count=$((count+1))
    fi
done
echo "You entered $count positive number(s)"
```

my try:

```
while (i<=n)
echo "Enter a number"
read a
if ((a>0))
    then
    count=$((count+1))
i++
```

i dont know if i fully understand while and for loops. Thanks for your help ^_^

Comment: What is your question? In what way don't your attempt work?

Comment: As I commented on your other question: That's bash, not csh. They're two different shells, with very different syntax. (And bash is much better for scripting.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is almost right; however you forgot to initialize i=1 before entering the while loop, and the do/done keywords

Comment: hmm, do goes right after the while (i<=n), and the done goes after the i++?

Comment: thanks aaa,  trying to learn csh!!! maybe you can help me with my other question i posted a minute ago :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626144/assistance-with-cshell-arithmetic-function

Comment: @LeeHurlbert: You're not learning csh; your script is a bash script. Which is a good thing (see [here](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot)), but if you actually want to learn csh programming that's not what you're doing.