# Assistance with bash arithmetic function

Tags: bash

I'm pretty fluent with Java but I'm having a difficult transition into bash

Complete the function named `arith` below to accomplish the following tasks:

- if the value of the variable a is less than the value of the variable b then call the function add,
- otherwise call the function sub.

So, the code so far is:

```
echo "Enter two integers on separate lines"
read a
read b

add()
{
  echo "$a + $b = $((a + b))"
}

sub()
{
  echo "$a - $b = $((a - b))"
}

arith()
{
  If{... # To be completed
}
```

I think it's supposed to be in the format of

```
arith()
{
    //if(a<b, call function add)
    //else(call function sub)
```

but I'm not sure how to write that.

Comment: That's bash, not csh. They're two different shells, with very different syntax. (And bash is much better for scripting.)

Comment: thank you for that, i tagged it improperly

Comment: You also mention csh in the title and in the first paragraph of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except that functions should probably not be accessing global variables, you might write either:

```
arith()
{
    if [ "$a" -lt "$b" ]
    then add
    else sub
    fi
}
```

Or:

```
arith()
{
    if [[ "$a" < "$b" ]]
    then add
    else sub
    fi
}
```

Normally, you'd write code more like:

```
add()
{
    echo "$1 + $2 = $(($1 + $2))"
}

sub()
{
    echo "$1 - $2 = $(($1 - $2))"
}

arith()
{
    if [[ "$1" < "$2" ]]
    then add "$1" "$2"
    else sub "$1" "$2"
    fi
}
```

Hence:

```
$ arith 1 2
1 + 2 = 3
$ arith 2 1
2 - 1 = 1
$ arith 1 1
1 - 1 = 0
$
```